# HTML: unwanted line break after a " quote character

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

In an HTML page, I want to use the expression `"<all_urls>"`:

```
<code>"&lt;all_urls&gt;"</code>
```

However, it can happen that this expression appears at the end of a line, and it wraps to the next line after the opening `"`, like this:

> something I want to say about "
>   <all_urls>"

I'm thinking I should be give this `<code>` tag a CSS rule that prevents the string inside it from breaking at any point. What rule would that be?

Comment: How about `white-space:nowrap;`? can you provide a live demo?

Comment: it must be an interaction with something else in your markup or CSS, because [it doesn't happen for me](https://jsfiddle.net/zpkj9k0n/). can you create an MCVE?

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow He mentions that it happens when it is at the end of a line. It breaks because the less-than sign is considered punctuation, just like the quote mark.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you have some text. So, you text as I guess, included in `p` tag. Just give to in `display: inline-block;` and everything will work!

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AleshaOleg/55Lt0z24/).

```css
p, code {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  something I want to say about something I want to say about something I want to say about&nbsp;<code>&quot;&lt;all_urls&gt;&quot;</code> something I want to say about something I want to say about something I want to say about
</p>
```